# Setting AlarmManager in a Broadcast Receiver to call another activity/service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a broadcast receiver and I want to initiate another activity/service using an alarm manager. So I want to set an alarm manager in my broadcast receiver to start the activity dynamically. Is it possible. Please tell guide me accordingly.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do You want to Show us a Little bit of Your code? We can´t exactly answer if You do not explain a bit more. But starting activity from broadcast Receiver is just simple as starting activity in the usual way:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   context.startActivity(intent);
```

Use this in Your onReceive()....and don´t Forget to Register Your Receiver to the manifest.

### EDIT

So if You want to start an Action 5 minutes after reboot, it should be something like this:

start another boradcastreceiver in Your BootCompleted Receiver:

```
   AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

   Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondBroadcastReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
   intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
   am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
   System.currentTimeMillis() + 300000, pendingIntent); //5 minutes are 300000 MS
```

### The BroadcastReceiver:

```
        public class SecondBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



       @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

              Intent i= new Intent(context, YourService.class);

              context.startService(i); 

           }
       }
```

### The Service

```
    public class YourService extends Service {

       @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       //start here the Action You will do, 5 minutes after reboot

       return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
   }

      @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

       return null;
    }
}
```

But this is only from scratch, I can´t test the code for now, have no IDE here. So I am not sure about givin the context to Intent and PendingIntent in Your BootCompletedReceiver.

Comment: I want to to start my service/activity from alarmManagaer and that alarm manager must be in the broadcast receiver. 
For example I have a working broadcast receiver for reboot. As the mobile reboots code in OnRecieve() got executed So my problem is that I want to schedule a service after 5 minutes mobile reboot. So i should have a alam manager which will start service after mobile reboot.